# Why is the exterior part of my left foot Toe is ALWAYS in pain

Tags: pain, feet, toe, podiatry

i've always experienced a little pain in this area :

[image]

but lately it became REALLY painful specially after wearing shoes for few hours, and the slightest hit on it really causes a lot pf pain.

notes:

- there is no weird color
- there is no "yellow/white liquid" coming out of it (dont know its name)
- it is slightly "inflated", like a liiitle bit compared to other toe.
- I am 23 years old, male.
- I am really picky with shoes and i choose the most comfortable ones (Sport Nike shoes) and my right foot totally agree with that.

PS : 
Am currently on vacation out of the country so i cant visit doctors, i just want some insights/advice please

thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue, which turned out to be pretty simple: I had missed a part of my toenail when trimming it.

[image: jutting out corner of a toenail]

The part wasn't actually visible as I've drawn it here—it was in between the skin there. As the toenail grew, that part began to painfully poke into the skin, especially when wearing shoes.

The pain disappeared immediately on trimming off this part:

[image]

Reaching all that way in to the edge of the nail was difficult with ordinary nail clippers (which is why I had missed it), but much easier with nail scissors:

[image: nail scissors]

Comment: Man i think you're right !!

Comment: i just double checked and found what you're talking about, used that scissor and apperantly the problem is solved, toe still hurt a little (and inflated) but hopefully it will go away, THANKS ALOT!! 
(sorry for double comment, forgot that "Enter" = confirm, not "line return")

Comment: @alaslipknot Posting thanks is fine but you should upvote the answer.

Comment: @CareyGregory i actually did upvoted it and marked it as correct answer, for some reason my vote was removed...

Comment: @alaslipknot Hmm... strange. Well, it appears to be there now so all's well.